# Only convert a subset of iprange to ip array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a range of ip addresses that thanks to some google fu I have been able to take the range and convert to an array of IP addresses. However I am running out of memory when the script is ran against a range of say 10.234.xxx.1/24. As such I am trying to see if there is a way to pull out a subset of 32 addresses so that I don't have this extra memory usage.

```
  ips.each do |ip|
    ip_from = ip.instance_of?(Nexpose::HostName) ? ip.host : (ip.from..ip.to).map(&:to_s)
    ip_from2 = ip_from.select{ |i| /[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.([2-3][0-9]|64)$/ =~ i }
    ip_from2.each do |ip2|
      log.log_debug_message("Getting credentials for #{ip2}")
      secret_summary = ss.get_secret_id(token, ip2)
      unless secret_summary.nil?
        log.log_debug_message("Found credentials for #{ip2}")
        # Gets OS
        asset_data = {}
        asset_data[:ip] = ip2
        res = ss.get_secret_simple(token, secret_summary[:secret_id])
        asset_data[:username] = res[:username]
        asset_data[:password] = res[:password]
        credential = Nexpose::SiteCredential.for_service(ss.check_type(secret_summary[:secret_type]),
                                                    asset_data[:username],
                                                    asset_data[:password],
                                                    nil,
                                                    ip2)
```

I would like to only have it hold 32 addresses in the array as you can see in the select statement on line 3. Any help is appreciated.

Sidenote: I have modified the nexpose_thycotic gem to make this work for my purposes. I am working through rapid7 as well but I was hoping someone on StackOverflow may be able to answer a little quicker as this is a time sensitive matter.

Comment: A `/24` is only 256 addresses, so if you're having memory problems you should dig deeper to find out why.

Comment: I agree, it seems like it shouldn't run out of memory, the total amount between all the subnets in the site is roughly 415, but with 8gb of ram I am still at a loss as to why I'm running out of memory. If I run the code against a smaller subset it works fine. I don't know the limit yet but I do know against say 24 ip addresses it doesn't choke out.

Comment: My usual technique in situations like this is to delete or comment out code until the problem goes away, then enable things selectively until it happens again, finding out precisely what triggers that behaviour.

Comment: With the way lines are printed to the screen in the code previous to this section, it is this section that is causing the problem. My issue is I'm not adept with the debugging tools to see why the memory just keeps increasing as soon as it goes to create the array in line 2.

Comment: Ran a heap dump and the file became 13Gb in size. Not sure what to look for at the moment as every parse method fails due to size, however I the best I can tell is it is holding on to each ip address so in total 449 ip addresses and is allocating 40bytes to each address. It is then holding on to each address and never releases the arrays.

Comment: Heap dumps aren't very useful. Like I said, try and disable code until the problem goes away, then carefully re-enable things until it comes back. You may be creating huge garbage-filled structures the garbage collector can't deal with.

Comment: I found the memory leak, problem is it is a necessary function and I don't know how to fix it. Where it maps out the IP Range in line 2 (ip.from..ip.to).map(&to_s) it consumes all available memory and swap. So how can I get the same results without the memory consumption?

Comment: What values of `from` and `to` are you dealing with when that happens?